# What is the third parameter "primer" in the lightning-datatable sort example?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

The example "Datatable with Sortable Column" (from the [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) documentation) includes this code where a `primer` parameter is declared and used in the `sortBy` function:

```
sortBy(field, reverse, primer) {
    const key = primer
        ? function (x) {
              return primer(x[field]);
          }
        : function (x) {
              return x[field];
          };

    return function (a, b) {
        a = key(a);
        b = key(b);
        return reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
    };
}

onHandleSort(event) {
    const { fieldName: sortedBy, sortDirection } = event.detail;
    const cloneData = [...this.data];

    cloneData.sort(this.sortBy(sortedBy, sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1 : -1));
    this.data = cloneData;
    this.sortDirection = sortDirection;
    this.sortedBy = sortedBy;
}
```

In a quick test, it is always `undefined`. What is its purpose, when is it populated and where is it documented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`primer` is just a function that does something to "prime" the data. For example, you might use it to make all the values lowercase, or uppercase, or round to the second significant digit, or whatever else you might want to do.

Examples:

```
// sort by uppercase letters, works for anything that can be coerced to a string
const uppercase = (x) => (x+'').toUpperCase();
this.sortBy(this.sortField, this.sortOrder, uppercase);

// Sort non-empty values
const truthy = (x) => (!!x);
this.sortBy(this.sortField, this.sortOrder, truthy);

// sort numbers in lexicographical order
const toString = (x) => x+'';
this.sortBy(this.sortField, this.sortOrder, toString);
```

It's useful to have this capability in many different sort algorithms, but the documentation doesn't actively use it, as you've observed.

Comment: Got it; thanks!